# Can't run gin gonic server on domain using aws ec2

Tags: go, nginx, go-gin

I have a domain on godaddy.com which I've given the DNS of my AWS EC2.
I can successfully run a flask application with the code

`app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, debug=True,ssl_context=('fullchain.pem', 'privkey.pem'))`
If I open the link https://typearncontrol.com:8000/latest in my browser I would get a result.

I'm trying to run a gin gonic application with the code

`router.RunTLS(("0.0.0.0:8083"),"fullchain.pem","privkey.pem")`
When I try to open the link https://typearncontrol.com:8083/2 which is a page of my gin app I get the error "This site can’t be reached"

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: Just to make sure: since you're running on AWS EC2, did you grant appropriate access to port `8083` for your EC2 instance in the security group? See e.g.: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-http-https-ec2/

To test it easily, try to run your service on `8000` just like you did for your `flask` service.

Comment: Do you have the appropriate permission for running the app on port ```8083```? Did you change the development mode of the ```gin```? I mean you need to set that mode to production.